# Safe way to read PHP response from C# application

Tags: c#, php, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

As the title of the topic may suggest, I have a PHP script setup on my server that, when called upon, is spitting data back to the user by echoing it back onto the page. I am then using `HttpWebRequest` to read the data that was put onto the page by the PHP script. While this data *is* encrypted, I would like for it to not appear on the page at all. I figured there must be a better way to go about doing this.

If I have been unclear thus far regarding my intentions, I am looking for some way to return data from a PHP page, so that I can retrieve it using `HTTPWebResponse`. Perhaps, for example, I could POST the data? I'm quite new to PHP so I figured I'd ask the experts here.

Thank you for any help,

Evan

Answer (score 1):

I think the best safe way is use RSA Encrypt in .NET. You can read and download project at [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/cs2phpcryptography.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can't post the data to the application, unless the application was a webserver. There's not really much other way to do it than the way you are doing it already.

Comment: How about using  print_r($_GET)

Comment: What? That solves nothing. He's already doing something similar.

Comment: @CommunistPancake That was embarrassing .... I was just curious if it made any difference. Still, quite embarrassing on your end.

Comment: Hmm? Why is it embarrassing for me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Since you're using http, it's logical to echo the data in the request stream within your php script. This way the other side (your .NET code can pick it up). If this is a problem for you, there are a few workarounds.

a: call your PHP script from .NET with a callback url refering back to your .NET application. Now the PHP script can actually post data back to the callback url. This however requires your .NET app to host a webservice.

b: you can put certain data in your php script without actually putting it in the request body by making it a mime header field like:

```
header('X-MyProject-Name: ' .$name);
header('X-MyProject-Age: ' .$age);
header('X-MyProject-Address: ' base64_encode(json_encode($complexAddressObject)));
```

Hope this helps